# ajax 419 Error in Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

Hello i am having a 419 Error that keeps on showing even when i try switching techniques between blade syntax url, normal javasript url ,jason data format or sending my data with the url .Please Help 
i also included X-CSRF in the head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

My call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
});
$.ajax({
  url:'{{url("/HeatMapCoordinates")}}',
  data:{"finalPointArray" :finalPointsMap,
        "tourId":tourId
        },
  dataType: 'html',
  async:true,
  type:'post',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success:function(response){
    console.log('response');
  },
  error:function(e){
    console.log('error');
  }
});
}
```

my route:
    Route::resource('/HeatMapCoordinates','HeatMapCoordinatesController');
My Controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, array(
            'finalPointArray' => 'required',
            'tourId' => 'required',
        ));
```

.....
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent included the CSRF token. The field is called `csrf-token` not `_token` and it needst to be contained in `""` to be a valid selector.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } 
});
```

Comment: Hello @mikeMiller Thank you for your suggestion But the console showed me this error when i tried it. Any idea what caused it?  Error: app.js:1 POST http://localhost/switch_to_vr/public/HeatMapCoordinates 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: `422` status code related Laravel validation. Are you sure, Do you post required data and right format ?

Comment: @SandyAlAkhras that is as @webdevtr says a validation error so you probably have null value inside one of your JS variables; `finalPointsMap` or `tourId`. If you do `console.log( finalPointsMap , tourId )` it will show you which are null. Alternatively inspect the response body by doing `console.log(e)` to see the validation messages from your API

Comment: Worked turns out i had a syntax error in the controller which caused the the 422 (Unprocessable Entity) error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When trying to call a controller route in ajax, you do not need to use the blade syntax for it. You can simply just call the url like this

`url: '/HeatMapCoordinates'`

If you have included a `csrf` token in your html page, try to include this on your ajax data

`'_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),`

Your code will look like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/HeatMapCoordinates',
  data:{ 
           "_token": $('input[name=_token]').val(),
           "finalPointArray" :finalPointsMap,
           "tourId":tourId
        },
```